# Python 3 split('\n')

Tags: python-3.x

How do I split a text string according to an explicit newline ('\n')?

Unfortunately, instead of a properly formatted csv file, I am dealing with a long string of text with "\n" where the newline would be. (example format: "A0,B0\nA1,B1\nA2,B2\nA3,B3\n ...") I thought a simple `bad_csv_list = text.split('\n')` would give me a list of the two-valued cells (example split ['A0,B0', 'A1,B1', 'A2,B2', 'A3,B3', ...]). Instead I end up with one cell and "\n" gets converted to "\\n". I tried copy-pasting a section of the string and using split('\n') and it works as I had hoped. The print statement for the file object tells me the following:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='stats.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

...so I suspect the problem is with the cp1252 encoding? Of note tho: Notepad++ says the file I am working with is "UTF-8 without BOM"... I've looked in the docs and around SO and tried importing io and codec and prepending the `open` statement and declaring `encoding='utf8'` but I am at a loss and I don't really grok text encoding. Maybe there is a better solution?

```
from sys import argv
# import io, codec

filename = argv[1]
file_object = open(filename, 'r')
# file_object = io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8')
# file_object = codec.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8')
file_contents = file_object.read()
file_list = file_contents.split('\n')

print("1.) Here's the name of the file: {}".format(filename))
print("2.) Here's the file object info: {}".format(file_object))
print("3.) Here's all the files contents:\n{}".format(file_contents))
print("4.) Here's a list of the file contents:\n{}".format(file_list))
```

Any  help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

If it helps to explain what I am dealing with, here's the contents of the stats.csv file:

```
Albuquerque,749\nAnaheim,371\nAnchorage,828\nArlington,503\nAtlanta,1379\nAurora,425\nAustin,408\nBakersfield,542\nBaltimore,1405\nBoston,835\nBuffalo,1288\nCharlotte-Mecklenburg,647\nCincinnati,974\nCleveland,1383\nColorado Springs,455\nCorpus Christi,658\nDallas,675\nDenver,615\nDetroit,2122\nEl Paso,423\nFort Wayne,362\nFort Worth,587\nFresno,543\nGreensboro,563\nHenderson,168\nHouston,992\nIndianapolis,1185\nJacksonville,617\nJersey City,734\nKansas City,1263\nLas Vegas,784\nLexington,352\nLincoln,397\nLong Beach,575\nLos Angeles,481\nLouisville Metro,598\nMemphis,1750\nMesa,399\nMiami,1172\nMilwaukee,1294\nMinneapolis,992\nMobile,522\nNashville,1216\nNew Orleans,815\nNew York,639\nNewark,1154\nOakland,1993\nOklahoma City,919\nOmaha,594\nPhiladelphia,1160\nPhoenix,636\nPittsburgh,752\nPlano,130\nPortland,517\nRaleigh,423\nRiverside,443\nSacramento,738\nSan Antonio,503\nSan Diego,413\nSan Francisco,704\nSan Jose,363\nSanta Ana,401\nSeattle,597\nSt. Louis,1776\nSt. Paul,722\nStockton,1548\nTampa,616\nToledo,1171\nTucson,724\nTulsa,990\nVirginia Beach,169\nWashington,1177\nWichita,742
```

And the result from the split('\n'):

```
['Albuquerque,749\\nAnaheim,371\\nAnchorage,828\\nArlington,503\\nAtlanta,1379\\nAurora,425\\nAustin,408\\nBakersfield,542\\nBaltimore,1405\\nBoston,835\\nBuffalo,1288\\nCharlotte-Mecklenburg,647\\nCincinnati,974\\nCleveland,1383\\nColorado Springs,455\\nCorpus Christi,658\\nDallas,675\\nDenver,615\\nDetroit,2122\\nEl Paso,423\\nFort Wayne,362\\nFort Worth,587\\nFresno,543\\nGreensboro,563\\nHenderson,168\\nHouston,992\\nIndianapolis,1185\\nJacksonville,617\\nJersey City,734\\nKansas City,1263\\nLas Vegas,784\\nLexington,352\\nLincoln,397\\nLong Beach,575\\nLos Angeles,481\\nLouisville Metro,598\\nMemphis,1750\\nMesa,399\\nMiami,1172\\nMilwaukee,1294\\nMinneapolis,992\\nMobile,522\\nNashville,1216\\nNew Orleans,815\\nNew York,639\\nNewark,1154\\nOakland,1993\\nOklahoma City,919\\nOmaha,594\\nPhiladelphia,1160\\nPhoenix,636\\nPittsburgh,752\\nPlano,130\\nPortland,517\\nRaleigh,423\\nRiverside,443\\nSacramento,738\\nSan Antonio,503\\nSan Diego,413\\nSan Francisco,704\\nSan Jose,363\\nSanta Ana,401\\nSeattle,597\\nSt. Louis,1776\\nSt. Paul,722\\nStockton,1548\\nTampa,616\\nToledo,1171\\nTucson,724\\nTulsa,990\\nVirginia Beach,169\\nWashington,1177\\nWichita,742']
```

Why does it ADD a \ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dOh!!! ROYAL FACE PALM! I just wrote all this out an then realized that all I needed to do was put an escape slash before the \newline:

```
file_list = file_contents.split('\\n')
```

I'm gonna post this anyways so y'all can have a chuckle ^_^

Comment: I was just gonna answer this... ;-;